# how to fixed this error for my code

Tags: syntax-error

```
'import java.awt.*;'
'import java.awt.event.*;'

'public void close(){'
'WindowEvent winClosingEvent = new WindowEvent(this,WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);'
    'Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(winClosingEvent);
    }'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will help you out......

```
public void close() {   
        Window win = new Window(new Frame());
        WindowEvent winClosingEvent = new WindowEvent(win, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSED); 
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(winClosingEvent);
    }
```